# Pound Sign not in a code block causes layout issue

Tags: bug, design, code-block

I ran across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415397/sql-state-error-relating-to-unknown-column-in-magento-db) which was originally posted with the error message/log details that were not placed in a code block.

Before it was in a code block, it caused the text to overflow to the right of the screen and ran under related posts sidebar.

You can see this when you go into the [Edit Revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15415397/revisions).

If you go into the original version and edit, you can see the overflow issue in the screenshot:

[image]

Is this something that can be caught before the layout gets all funky?  Or can those pound signs be escaped some how so the layout doesn't break?

Comment: Put it into a code block.  Markdown uses `#` for H1 tags.

Comment: I did put it in a code block, but the user originally posted the question without the code block and the layout was broken.  I am trying to figure out if there is a way to automatically escape those if it doesn't get put in a code block.

Answer (score 12):

## Apparently_the_code_that_wraps_header_text_can't_handle_long_lines_without_spaces.

This happens whether prefixing the text with a '#' character or underlining with '='.  It looks like h2 headers are affected as well, though of course they have to have more text.

---

**Update:**  Hey!  Now it's fixed!  Good work team!

Comment: Thanks for showing how it breaks! :)

Comment: Well played.  A perfect example of something I've seen a few times as well.